# How can I change the pre-trained file of the Yolov4 algorithm?

Tags: label, yolo, darknet, yolov4

I want to train my custom dataset using the yolov4 algorithm.
The difference between my data and the coco dataset is that my objects label's are as follows:

`label annotation:  <object-class> <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height> <d>`

We always use [pre-trained files](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#pre-trained-models) to object detection, but given that my data has different labels, Do I need to change pre-trained data?
how should I train the dataset?